# First build - Quadcopter , need help deciding hardware and connections

Tags: quadcopter, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am building my first drone,

> Objective: - Need to control drone by wifi on phone or laptop using
>   ground station software of Openpilot

I have a Arduino 2560 , cc3d Openpilot flight controller , raspberry pi with wifi bluetooth in built...

Now i am not able to understand , how to go forward , should i connect arduino with openpilot cc3d flight controller , or raspberry pi directory with cc3d flight controller ....

Do i really need arduino 2560 now ?

also how to connect r pi with cc3d flight controller , and how to mock PWM signals ?

Comment: Welcome to *robotics* anshulkatta, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](http://meta.robotics.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are connecting the Flight Controller directly to the Arduino / PI within the drone.

If you are then ditch the Arduino Mega and the PI and use a Nano.  It will still provide you with 6PWM pins.
The PI is going to require a "Hat" to generate PWM as far as I can tell, and the Mega is just to damn big and heavy.

Comment: what is a nano ? , can you name the device fully , with Rpi and flight controller , i will be able to program r pi to get info from internet and send signals to motor via cc3d... thats why i am going to join r pi wth cc3d

Comment: @anshulkatta by Nano I mean an "Arduino Nano" (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoNano) Its not quite as capable as the Arduino Uno (I think) but its the size of your thumb, well my thumb.  Using a Pi for real time control may prevent issues because of the operating system, you can't rely on a multithreaded OS for flight control.  An alternative might be an ESP8266 + Nano combination. Program the ESP using the Arduino IDE, not using AT commands, and then use the Nano for the PWM (can't remember if ESP does PWM)